# Highchart-vuejs wrapper- passing variable from a Vuejs method into Highchart data series

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have used the vuejs-neo4j connector to run a query and get a node from my neo4j database. I now want to pass this output into the data series of the highchart. Is there a way to pass the variable with the data  from methods into the chart series data?

**Vuejs method**

```
methods: {
connect() {
  return this.$neo4j
    .connect(
      this.protocol,
      this.host,
      this.port,
      this.username,
      this.password
    )
    .then(driver => (this.driver = driver))
    .catch(e => (this.error = e));
},

testQuery() {
  // Get a session from the driver
  const session = this.$neo4j.getSession();

  // Or you can just call this.$neo4j.run(cypher, params)
  session
    .run("MATCH (node:player) RETURN count(node) AS data")
    .then(res => {
      var data = res.records[0].get("data");
      var amnts = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(amnts);
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data;
    })
    .then(() => {
      session.close();
    });
}
```

},

**Highchart code**

```
title: "",
  chartType: "bar",
  seriesColor: "#6fcd98",
  colorInputIsSupported: null,
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      type: "bar"
    },
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: "text"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "asdad"
        }
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [],
        color: "red"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Yes, you can set data from methods. Check this demo with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj?file=/src/components/Chart.vue. Do you use highcharts-vue wrapper? It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue.

Comment: Hey this helped me thanks but i am still stuck, my issue is that i stored my data from the database in a variable (data) in another method testQuery(), and now need to access that variable in the click() method. How do i do it?

Comment: You have to save the data from the database in the component data then you can access it from the click method. DOCS: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html